# Create a Cloudrun Job programmatically with Cloud SQL access?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I need to create a cloudrun job programmatically that can access a cloudsql instance. Looking at the yml from the a job I created successfully in the console, it looks like that is controlled with annotations like `run.googleapis.com/cloudsql-instances` and `run.googleapis.com/vpc-access-connector`. When I try to add those annotations in the java builder:

```
                  builder.putAnnotations(
                          "run.googleapis.com/cloudsql-instances",
                          "my-instance")
```

I ultimately get an error:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Violation in CreateJobRequest.job.template.annotations[run.googleapis.com/vpc-access-egress]: system annotations are not supported in Cloud Run API v2.
```

Which makes me think the annotations starting with `run.googleapis.com` are not allowed. If that is the case, is it impossible to connect to a private cloudsql database when I am creating a job programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

The yaml you're looking at is for the Cloud Run v1 API but you're using the v2 API. In v2, VPC settings are a field in the template rather than an annotation. You can see the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v2/TaskTemplate